# Where should JSF 2.2 resources be placed: WEB-INF or root

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Before JSF 2.2, resources such as javascript, css and composite components would be placed at the root of a web archive in a `/resources` folder. A security constraint in WEB-INF would accompany this setup to prevent direct access:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to JSF resources</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSF resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

In JSF 2.2, however, you can simply put the resources folder in WEB-INF: `/WEB-INF/resources`. This gives the resources implicit protection from direct access.

`WEB-INF` according to [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/source.html#Directory_Structure) and [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ablxhelp/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.abx.adm.doc/admin17.htm) describes it as a folder to store configuration files. It seems like a hack to put non configuration resources in `WEB-INF` just to gain the protection of the `WEB-INF` directory.

Are both methods of storing the resources identical in their effect? Are their any concrete drawbacks to either method?

Comment: Hack? Why? putting it under *root/resources/* does nothing but give you the added work of securing it yourself. Half the benefit of there being a *WEB-INF* in the first place is the protection. Besides, you're not constrained to *WEB-INF*; You're also allowed to jar your resources into *META-INF*. What you settle for is *primarily opinion-based*

Comment: I questioned whether it was a hack because the I was under the impression that the WEB-INF folder was intended for configuration/metadata files. If not, what exactly is the purpose of the `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: Personally, I never considered resources in the WEB-INF folder a hack. But you are right, the Servlet (3.0) specification emphasizes the importance of that folder for "configuration information".
Btw, where did you find the recommendation for `/WEB-INF/resources` in the JSF 2.2 specification? I do not find anything of that kind there.

Answer (score 0):

You can safety put resources under WEB-INF it will save you from the mistake of forget to protect it from directly access, nothing more ! If you wanna keep in root with protection the effect will be the same.